Oracle Forms 12.2.1.4.0 Concurrent Users issue: Insufficient Privileges Error on Record Creation
Here is the situation. I have two users who are attempting to use this Oracle Forms application at the same time. The minimum required to replicate the error is:

Both users open their respective forms (which use the same tables as data blocks.)
User 1 enters details for a new PAYEE record, saves that record, and begins entering data for other data blocks.
User 2 enters details for a new PAYEE record, attempts to save, and receives the Insufficient Privilege error on the INSERT statement (this user does have INSERT privilege on the table)

Locking mode on the data block is Delayed, and every items' Lock Record property is set to No. I've inherited this application and don't have any experience with Forms apart from my knowledge of SQL and PL/SQL. My initial thought is perhaps the insufficient privilege error is due to the sequence used to generate the record id, but if the first user has saved the record, shouldn't that free up the sequence?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

With problems like this I always recommend you start with the simplest first.  Assume that the error is valid.  While in this state, go to the DB using Sql+ or SqlDev and determine the state of the table and/or record.  Verify for example that the record in question is not actually locked.  Try making an update to it (outside of Forms).  If you cannot then you can assume that the first user change was not actually saved.  If you can, then the error might be correct in the current context and further investigation of what the form is doing may be needed.

MichaelJF was correct.
PEBKAC (x2)

I believed the user when they said they said they successfully entered a record.
The user did not have the necessary privilege to insert a record.

Adding the privileges resolved the issue.
